# Is there a better algorithm for exercise 9.3 in 《Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist》

Tags: python, algorithm

The [exercise 9.3](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython010.html#toc101) in this book ask the reader to find a combination of 5 forbidden letters that excludes the smallest number of words in [this file](http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt).

Below is my solution for the first part, I think there is no problem for them

```
# if the word contain any letter in letters, return True,
# otherwise return False
def contain(word, letters):
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in word:
            return True
    return False

# return the number of words contain any letter in letters
def ncont(words, letters):
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        if contain(word, letters):
            count += 1
return count
```

But for the question above, I can only think of a brute-force algorithm, that is, try every kind of possible combination, there are exactly 26! / 5! = 65780 kind of combination, below is the implementation:

```
def get_lset(nlt, alphabet, cur_set):
    global min_n, min_set
    # when get enough letters 
    if nlt <= 0:
        cur_n = ncont(words, ''.join(cur_set))
        if min_n == -1 or cur_n < min_n:
            min_n = cur_n
            min_set = cur_set.copy()
        print(''.join(cur_set), cur_n, ' *->', min_n, ''.join(min_set))
    # otherwise find the result letters in a recursive way
    else:
        cur_set.append(None)
        for i in range(len(alphabet)):
            cur_set[-1] = alphabet[i]
            get_lset(nlt-1, alphabet[i+1:], cur_set)
        cur_set.pop()
```

and then call the above function like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    min_n = -1
    min_set = []
    with open('words.txt', 'r') as fin:
        words = [line.strip() for line in fin]
    get_lset(5, list(string.ascii_lowercase), [])
    print(min_set, min_n)
```

but this solution is very slow, and I'd like to know is there a better algorithm for this question? Any suggestion will be good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's rewrite it more concisely

```
def contain(word, letters):
    return any(letter in word for letter in letters)

def ncont(words, letters):
    return sum(contain(word, letters) for word in words):
```

At the moment your algorithm has average complexity

```
O(len(letters) * len(a_word) * len(words))
  ---+----------------------   -+--------
     contain(word, letters)     ncont(words, letters)
```

We can reduce this by using `set`s:

```
def contain(word, letters):
    return not set(letters).isdisjoint(set(word))
```

Which reduces to:

```
O(min(len(letters), len(a_word)) * len(words))
  ---+--------------------------   -+--------
     contain(word, letters)        ncont(words, letters)
```

According to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

---

As for the second part, the algorithm would be easier to understand with itertools:

```
import itertools

def minimum_letter_set(words, n):
    attempts = itertools.combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, n)
    return min(attempts, key=lambda attempt: ncont(words, attempt))
```

However, we can do much better:

```
def minimum_letter_set(words, n):
    # build a lookup table for each letter to the set of words it features in
    by_letter = {
        letter: {
            word
            for word in words
            if letter in word
        }
        for letter in string.ascii_lowercase
    }

    # allowing us to define a function that finds words that match multiple letters
    def matching_words(letters):
        return set.union(*(by_letter[l] for l in letters))

    # find all 5 letter combinations
    attempts = itertools.combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, n)

    # and return the one that matches the fewest words
    return min(attempts, key=lambda a: len(matching_words(a))))
```

I'm not convinced this has any lower an algorithmic complexity, but it certainly saves the repeated work of filtering the word list.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's a great example to show the power of python's concise, and the function become faster than original implementation. And do you have any suggestion for the second part, find the set of 5 letters which can get the minimum number of words? I think the brute-force algorithm is not good enough

Comment: That's great, functional programming style seems a good way to make the program more readable, thanks very much.

Comment: Not convinced I'd call this a functional programming style

Comment: I can't say exactly your final solution's time complexity, but it's an  new view to this problem, this is very important, and the program's readability is greatly improved, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea:

First compute excluded[l] that map letters to set of excluded word of letter l.

Compute the union of the five smallest of these 26 sets. This give you a fair "temporary minimum result".

Then, instead of using itertools.combinations to explore all combinations of 5 letters, write your own algo to do that. Compute the union of "excluded" set inside this. In this algo, if for the first i letters (i<5), the union of "excluded" set is already bigger than the "temporary minimum result", you don't need to consider following letters at all. When you find some five letter combination better than current "temporary minimum result", update it.

Comment: I'm glad you like it. If you implement it, please give some feedback.

Comment: Ok, I will try to implement it as soon as possible!

Comment: Hello, I have implemented your algorithm, it's amazing faster than the original one, thanks again.[Here](https://github.com/zbtong/pyexercise/blob/master/think-python/findmincomb.py) is the link to it, any suggestion?

Comment: It's faster than I thought. It works well because there is a large disparity between letters usage. Actually the first guess is the right one. This not the case with 6 letters, but with 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 first guess is enough. This means that for low usage letters, they are not so much correlated.

Comment: Thanks, I learn a lot of things in this conversation. It give me some guide when design algorithm. First, focus on the data, use the property the data have. For this problem, the large disparity between letter usage in natural language largely reduce the number of attempts; second, try to reduce the number of attempts in the midway, this is a more general guideline.

Answer (score 0):

My solution here:

```
    def smallest_set(filename):
        avoid_dict = dict.fromkeys(ascii_letters.lower(), 0)
        with open(filename) as file_handler:
            for line in file_handler:
                for key in avoid_dict:
                    if key not in line:
                        avoid_dict[key] += 1
        avoid_stats_sorted = sorted(avoid_dict, key=avoid_dict.get,
reverse=True)
        return ''.join([item for item in avoid_stats_sorted[:5]])
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, while this may answer the question, it is better to give explanations and not only code for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a faster solution, in my opinion.  Here is the code with comments ...

```
import itertools
import string
import timeit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start timestamp
    start_ts = timeit.default_timer()

    #
    # Small function to calculate the factorial of a number
    # Used in debugging
    #
    # Math: the number of unique combinations of x elements from y elements is calculated as
    #       y! / (y - x)! / x!
    #
    # Or, in 'school' notation
    #
    #          y!
    #    _____________
    #    (y - x)! . x!
    #
    fac = lambda num: 1 if num <= 1 else num * fac(num - 1)

    #
    # Open the file and read the content in memory as a list of strings
    #
    with open("words.txt", "r") as file:
        words = file.readlines()

    #
    # Create a dictionary containing the 26 letters of the English alphabet
    # For each of the letters, set the number the letter appears to 0
    #
    # I prefer to initialize this here instead of dynamically adding them to the dictionary later,
    # as normally this text file will contain all letters and having to check if the element exists will take longer
    #
    appearances = {}

    for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        appearances[letter] = 0

    #
    # For each of the words, each of the unique letters, count them into appearances
    # If a letter appears twice or even more, it does not matter.  We count the words that contain the letter
    # at least once.  For our letter set, it does not matter whether the letter appears once or more
    #
    for word in words:
        for letter in list(set(word.strip().lower())):
            appearances[letter] += 1

    # Debug: you will see Q has the least appearances, E has the most
    print(appearances)

    #
    # Let's sort this.  It's key to this algorythm
    #
    # In short:
    #
    # Suppose we only have 5 letters, A to E
    # Suppose we have counted our appearances and this is how many times they show up
    #   A : 10
    #   B : 5
    #   C : 3
    #   D : 7
    #   E : 12
    #
    # Sorted:
    #   C : 3, B: 5, D : 7, A : 10, E : 12
    #
    # Suppose we need combinations of only 2 letters
    # Take C + B
    # In worst case, you have in total 8 words that contain either C or B.  This is the case where no words have both.
    # In best case, you have 5.  This is the case where 3 words contain B and C, 2 words contain only B
    #
    # Given the above, it makes no sense to check any combination with A or E
    # You know they have either 10 or 12 words.  They can't beat B+C in number of appearances
    # So don't include them in the combinations.  This will significantly lower the number of combinations
    #
    # Given the above, you must include D, as you don't know how many words have either B or C (between 5 and 8)
    #
    # On the words.txt, this approach resulted in only 252 combinations to check.  So "with brute" force, you only
    # needed 252 iterations over the possible combinations of 5 characters.  You can verify with the debug code
    #
    #

    #
    # appearances_sorted is a list, we can't calculate on it
    #
    appearances_sorted = sorted(appearances, key=lambda x: appearances[x])

    print(appearances_sorted)
    print(appearances_sorted[:5])

    #
    # Calculate the least amount possible.  This is the sum of the 5 lowest appearances
    # As we are looping over the first 5, we already put them in our list of combinations to check
    #
    sum_least = 0
    appearances_least = {}

    for k in appearances_sorted[:5]:
        v = appearances[k]
        sum_least += v
        appearances_least[k] = v

    print(sum_least)
    print(appearances_least)

    #
    # For the rest of the sorted appearances, we add them, unless the appearance of the character by itself
    # is already higher than the sum we calculated
    #
    for k in appearances_sorted[5:]:
        if appearances[k] > sum_least:
            break

        appearances_least[k] = appearances[k]

    print(appearances_least)

    #
    # Debug code to check the math against the len of the calculations Python will provide
    #
    # f1 = fac(len(appearances_least))
    # f2 = fac(len(appearances_least) - 5)
    # f3 = fac(5)
    # print(f1 / f2 / f3)
    #

    #
    # Create all the possible combinations using itertools
    # One advantage is also that we can do this on a sorted list, the combinations with the smallest possible
    # appearances appear first.  But as said, as we don't know the words that have multiple letters combined, we
    # cannot be sure we only need to check the first
    #
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(appearances_least, 5))

    # This will print 252 on the words.txt file
    print(len(combinations))

    #
    # How many words in total do we have
    # This total will be used as a starting point to see how a combination is done
    # The worst combination possible will never be in more words than the file contains
    #
    total_words = len(words)
    min_found = total_words
    print(total_words)

    #
    # Just to avoid that PyCharm complains that best_combo might not be set later
    #
    best_combo = combinations[0]

    #
    # Loop over all the combos we have, as we cannot be sure on the words that have multiple letters
    # When we calculated the appearances, we were calculating only per letter
    #
    for combo in combinations:
        count_matches = 0

        #
        # Loop over the words, then over the letters in the combo
        # If one of the letters is found, add the counter and stop the loop as it does not matter if other characters
        # of the combo also appear.  One is enough to count it.
        #
        #
        for word in words:
            for letter in combo:
                if letter in word:
                    count_matches += 1
                    break

            #
            # If we already found more words than the minimum we have detected already, we can stop the loop.  This
            # combo will not be better, it will only get worse.
            #
            if count_matches > min_found:
                break

        #
        # If we found a better one, store it
        #
        if count_matches < min_found:
            best_combo = combo
            min_found = count_matches

    # End timestamp
    end_ts = timeit.default_timer()

    #
    # Print the results
    #
    print(best_combo)
    print(min_found)
    print(end_ts - start_ts)
    #
    # I have:
    #
    # ('q', 'j', 'x', 'z', 'w')
    # 17382
    # 4.387889001052827
    #
    # Enjoy !
```